# Can't change Databinding in Textblock when selectedItem in listview MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a problem . I can't change databind when I selecte Item in list view

**This My my code xaml ( View ):**

```
 <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding FCsource, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="10" Width="440" Height="220" >
                        <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Words, Mode = TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

**This My my code in ViewModel:**

public ObservableCollection _FCsource;

public ObservableCollection FCsource { get { return AddFlashCard(); } set { FCsource = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

```
private Item _SelectedItem;
public Item SelectedItem { get=>_SelectedItem; set
    {
        _SelectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if(_SelectedItem!=null)
        {
            SelectedItem.Words="hello"
        }
    }   
}
public WordsViewModel()
{

}

private ObservableCollection<Item> AddFlashCard()
{
    ObservableCollection<Item> listmn = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    listmn.Add(new Item("qwda");
    listmn.Add(new Item("qwda");
    listmn.Add(new Item("qwda");
    return listmn;
}
```

Comment: its not clear what you want to do and what is failing

Comment: @DenisSchaf I edit question again

Comment: @DenisSchaf  watch the question again. Maybe you can help me.please..

Comment: "I can't change databind" what does that mean?`
what do you want to do?

Comment: @DenisSchaf I want when I click ( selected item) in listview then item in listview change value databind, I'm addtional the question again,you should read code again

Answer (score 0):

With some changes to your code (you have compile errors in there) it works as expected. Predictably, it stops working if there is no `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface properly implemented on the `Item` class (specifically signaling changes of the `Words` property). That is probably what is causing your issue.

Below is the working code (the `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented here using `PropertyChanged.Fody version 2.6.0` nuget package):

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class WordsViewModel
{

    public ObservableCollection<WordItem> _FCsource;

    public ObservableCollection<WordItem> FCsource { get { return AddFlashCard(); } set { FCsource = value; } }

    private WordItem _SelectedItem;
    public WordItem SelectedItem
    {
        get => _SelectedItem; set
        {
            _SelectedItem = value;
            if (_SelectedItem != null)
            {
                SelectedItem.Words = "hello";
            }
        }
    }
    public WordsViewModel()
    {       
    }

    private ObservableCollection<WordItem> AddFlashCard()
    {
        ObservableCollection<WordItem> listmn = new ObservableCollection<WordItem>();
        listmn.Add(new WordItem("qwda"));
        listmn.Add(new WordItem("qwda"));
        listmn.Add(new WordItem("qwda"));
        return listmn;
    }
}

[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class WordItem
{
    public string Words { get; set; }
    public WordItem(string words)
    {
        Words = words;
    }
}
```

If you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly and it's still not working, then are you sure that you assigned your View Model to your View's DataContext?